# Gravity Forms address verification - require letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation, street-address, gravityforms

With Gravity Forms is there a way through field validation, or some other means, to prompt or require better address verification prior to form submission?

I'm trying to improve our form submissions and one of the areas that still presents potential issues is the address field. I have our Google Maps and Places API working properly to help users autocomplete their address but despite my best efforts, users can still provide incomplete and incorrect addresses. The street address field will currently allow a single digit to be submitted. I was hoping to prompt users to enter at least both a number and a letter but have no idea how to accomplish this from the gform_field_validation documentation on their site. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I've attempted to create an HTML message that appears with conditional logic but it is a limited UI that doesn't allow me to require both a number and a letter. I also feel just requiring a letter and number doesn't best address the validation issue and that perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)